# Center on screen two annotations while allowing MKCamera heading updates creates very jerky animations

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview

In my app, I have a mode that rotates the `MKMapView` camera heading based on Core Location heading updates. This works great.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
   self.mapView.camera.heading = theHeading;//Comes from CLHeading
} completion:nil];
```

At the same time, I have two annotations, one is the current location, that I always want to keep on screen. So as the user gets closer to one of the annotations, the map will continue to zoom in.

```
MKMapRect flyTo = MKMapRectNull;
if (location) {
    MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(location.coordinate);
    MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0, 0);
    if (MKMapRectIsNull(flyTo)) {
        flyTo = pointRect;
    } else {
        flyTo = MKMapRectUnion(flyTo, pointRect);
    }
}
if (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(self.selectedCoordinate)) {
    MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.selectedCoordinate);
    MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0, 0);
    if (MKMapRectIsNull(flyTo)) {
        flyTo = pointRect;
    } else {
        flyTo = MKMapRectUnion(flyTo, pointRect);
    }
}

[self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:flyTo edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 30, 30, 30) animated:animated];
```

**The Problem**

[image]

The big issue here, is that as the user rotates the device, and the heading is updated, the `visibleMapRect` is also updated to keep both annotations on the map. This causes the map to animate back to "north up" and then quickly back to rotating the map camera. This creates a very jerky movement which is not what I want.

Is it possible to set the `visibleMapRect` and the camera heading at the same time without this negative side effect?

Answer (score 0):

`camera` and `visibleMapRect` are two mutually exclusive ways to control what a mapView shows.

Don't mix them.

If you want smooth animations either always use `visibleMapRect` or always use `camera`:

```
setCamera(camera, animated: true)
```

Comment: Understood. But how could I center the camera on two annotations?

Comment: I don't do this at the moment. `CLLocation` has a method `distance` (result in meters). I'd measure the distance between the annotations using this method and test which factor is good to calculate the parameter `eyeAltitude` for the camera.

Comment: Calculate the center: make a small MKMapRect from each annotation.coodinate. Use MapRect.union to make one MapRect from the two MapRects. Get the center from the result MKMapRect.